# Shared configuration for multiple batch scripts

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Is it possible to have a batch file with some common variables and then include this script in other scripts so that the variables are visible there?

What is a common approach to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply, within the scripts that need to see the "shared" values

```
CALL yourbatchthatsetsthecommonvariables.bat
```

**BUT** changes to those variables will be isolated to the specific `CMD` instance - they won't be communicated between instances.

**AND** the values returned for any instance by this `COMMON.BAT` would be those relevant to the current instance.

So: Suppose you have `COMMON.BAT`

```
set mytime=%time%
set myval=abc123
```

Then instance 1... or instance 2

```
...
call COMMON.BAT
...
```

would set `myval` to `abc123` but `mytime` to the time that each called `COMMON.BAT`

Answer (score 1):

Try this (in the first script):

```
set>variables.txt
```

.. and in the second script:

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in (variables.txt) do set %%i
```

Edit:
To do this for a set of variables (first file):

```
::define some variables
set "_myvar1=value1"
set "_myvar2=value2"
set "_myvar3=value3"
::save them to a text file
set _myvar>variables.txt
```

This saves all variables heading `_myvar`to the text file. The code for the second script doesn't change.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely, and this is pretty common too.

Let's say your variables in `config.bat`:

```
set PATH=c:\opt\tools\jdk1.6;%PATH%
set CLASSPATH=c:\opt\projects\myproject\jars;%CLASSPATH%
```

Then you can have for example `start-dev.bat`:

```
call common.bat
javaw -cp %CLASSPATH% -Denv=dev
```

And `start-prod.bat`:

```
call common.bat
javaw -cp %CLASSPATH% -Denv=prod
```